# Why is my data empty when i add it to my dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I use a filter to check for conditions in my dataframe so i can mark them.

```
filtering = (dfsamen.shift(0).moving=='movingToclose') & (more condtions)
dffilter = pd.Dataframe(data=filtering, columns = ['filter'])
dffilter['DateTime'] = dfsamen['DateTime']
```

Output:

filtering

```
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
```

dffilter

```
4    False 2018-06-03 06:33:38.593
5    False 2018-06-03 06:33:39.197
6     True 2018-06-03 06:33:40.597
7     True 2018-06-03 06:33:41.800
```

But later I use the same code with different condtions and it doesn't work

```
filtering2 = (dfsamen.shift(0).Input5==1) | (more conditions)
dffilter2 = pd.DataFrame(data=filtering2, columns=['filter2'])
dffilter2['DateTime'] = dfsamen['DateTime']
```

Output:

filtering2

```
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
```

dffilter2 (before the datetime is added)

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [filter2]
Index: []
```

dffilter2 (with datetime)

```
4      NaN 2018-06-03 06:33:38.593
5      NaN 2018-06-03 06:33:39.197
6      NaN 2018-06-03 06:33:40.597
7      NaN 2018-06-03 06:33:41.800
```

So why does my data dissapear in the second filter when i add it to the column eventhough the data exists in the `filtering2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your `DataFrame` constructor,  because is created default `RangeIndex` so possible different indices in both DataFrames, data are not alignes and you get NaNs column for rows with different index values.

Solution is converting values to numpy arrays:

```
filtering = (dfsamen.shift(0).moving=='movingToclose') & (more condtions)

dffilter = pd.DataFrame(data=filtering.values, columns = ['filter'])
dffilter['DateTime'] = dfsamen['DateTime'].values
print (dffilter)
```

**Sample**:

```
dfsamen = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abc'),
        'DateTime':pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3),
        'C':[7,8,9]
}, index=[4,5,6])

print (dfsamen)
   A   DateTime  C
4  a 2015-01-01  7
5  b 2015-01-02  8
6  c 2015-01-03  9

filtering = dfsamen.A == 'a'

dffilter = pd.DataFrame(data=filtering.values, columns = ['filter'])
dffilter['DateTime'] = dfsamen['DateTime'].values
print (dffilter)
   filter   DateTime
0    True 2015-01-01
1   False 2015-01-02
2   False 2015-01-03
```

Or use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for converting `Series` to DataFrame with one column:

```
filtering = dfsamen.A == 'a'

dffilter = filtering.to_frame('filter')
dffilter['DateTime'] = dfsamen['DateTime'].values
print (dffilter)
   filter   DateTime
4    True 2015-01-01
5   False 2015-01-02
6   False 2015-01-03
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your explanation, since filtering and filtering2 have the exact same amount of rows and index. Only the ordering of the True and False are different.
So why does it work in the first case and not in the second?

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam - So what is `print (dffilter.index)` and `print (dffilter2.index)` ? Is it difference with `print (dfsamen.index)` ?

Comment: I worded my previous comment uncorrectly, i meant to say: "they should have the same index"
`print (dffilter.index)` gives me `Int64index([0, 1, to 31])`
`print (dffilter2.index)` gives me `Intdex([], dtype='object')` 
Since dffilter2 is empty this is expected. 

But `print(filtering2)` gives me a `True/False` column with the an index `[0, 1, to 31]`.

`print (dfsamen.index)` also gives me `Int64index([0, 1, to 31])`

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam - so problem is empty dataframe, so no index values.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why it is empty? since there is data in `filtering2` and i use that data to fill the column in the created dataframe with only that single column

Comment: I think there is problem passing Series to DataFrame, it create one column DataFrame - `pd.DataFrame(data=filtering)`.  But if pass columns parameter it failed - `dffilter = pd.DataFrame(data=filtering, columns = ['filter'])` - I think problem is different name of `filtering.name` what is converting to DataFrame column and `columns = ['filter']` - and it return empty DataFrame. Correct passing is `dffilter = pd.DataFrame({'filter':filtering})` or converting to numpy array `dffilter = pd.DataFrame(data=filtering.values, columns = ['filter'])`